# `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` doesn't output files which not tracked by git,what's the problem?

Tags: git

My system is centos 7.4 with git 1.8.3

When I want to list all files not tracked by git:

```
[root@localhost www]# git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
[root@localhost www]# git status
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**It seemed nothing is non_tracked.**

Then I run `git clean -fdxn`,output as below:
[root@localhost www]# git clean -fdxn

```
Would remove cms/template/
Would remove cms/tool/feedback/temp/
Would remove cms/update/
Would remove html/
Would remove images/
Would remove index.html
Would remove nbproject/
Would remove admin/application/config/config.php
Would remove welcome.html
```

**We can see lots of folders and files not_tracked.**
That's right,because those folders and files are listed in `.gitignore`.

I am confused.
For example, `welcome.html` is output of `git clean -fdxn`,which means `welcome.html` is not tracked.
Why doesn't `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` output `welcome.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` outputs no files because there are no files that are untracked and not ignored. Add a file that doesn't correspond to any pattern in `.gitignore` and retry — the file will be in the output.

To see all untracked files including ignored run simple `git ls-files --others`.